# How to generate package name on opening an android app?

Tags: android, android-studio

After searching for a while I have found how to generate package name but I am not able to generate the package name whenever someone opens or closes an app, does anyone have an idea how to go about it?
The code below is what I used for generating the package name.

```
public String getTopActivity() {
    String topPackageName = "";
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager) getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                // We get usage stats for the last 10 seconds
                List<UsageStats> stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, time - 1000 * 10, time);
                // Sort the stats by the last time used
                if (stats != null) {
                    SortedMap<Long, UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long, UsageStats>();
                    for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) {
                        mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(), usageStats);
                    }
                    if (mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) {
                        topPackageName = mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
                        Log.e("TopPackage Name", topPackageName);
                    }
                }
            }

    return topPackageName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand Activity Lifecycle for this. Here's an example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    show("onCreate");
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    show("onStart");
}

@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    show("onRestart");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    show("onResume");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    show("onPause: bye bye!");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    show("onStop.");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    show("onDestroy.");
}

private void show(String s) {
    Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now you can understand lifecycle, use those methods. Call `getTopActivity()` from methods like `onCreate`, `onStart()`, `onPause()`, etc. like,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getTopActivity();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getTopActivity();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getTopActivity();
}
```

See [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle) for more information and all such methods.